# Why would this only print the first line?

Tags: java, string, class

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ParseTheTweet {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner theScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

                    String tweet = "";




        System.out.println("Enter the tweet");
        tweet = theScanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println(tweet);
   }
}
```

This is the program I have so far, its very simple and I have a feeling I'm doing something very easy wrong.  I want the output variable tweet to be the same as the input, however it keeps only printing the first line.

ex.
input:

```
#typ offer; #det free essential supplies 4 evacs pets.; #loc 2323   
55th st, boulder; #lat 40.022; #lng -105.226;
```

output:

```
 #typ offer; #det free essential supplies 4 evacs pets.; #loc 2323
```

Comment: Why do you expect `Scanner.nextLine()` to return multiple lines?

Comment: need to do a while loop until scanner has EOL

Comment: what scanner object will read both of these lines?

Comment: you call `nextLine` multiple times, once for each line.  It is called `nextLine` not `allLines`

Comment: the input will always have 1 or two lines, though I don't want to ask the user for the number of lines, I automatically want it to read one or both.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to read more lines than just one, you need to call `theScanner.nextLine()` in a loop, e.g.:

```
while (theScanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String tweet = theScanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println(tweet);
}
```